# jenkins log parser plugin multiline errors

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've just installed log parser plugin for jenkins but it doesn't handle multiline errors. Is there a way to make that work?

I've tried:

```
^Caught exception(.*)(\n(.*)at (.*))+
```

and

```
^Caught exception(.*)(\s(.*)at (.*))+
```

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you give an example of a _"multiline error"_ you'd like to handle?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to find a solution to the same problem.

Lets assume this is a part of the console output:

```
1. some text
2. error_type first line
3. error_type second line
4. failed third line
5. some text
```

I want the text between 2nd and 4th lines to be marked as an error:

I tried the following, but it did not work

```
error /(?s)error_type(.*\s)failed/
```